# clang does not compile code that gcc compiles

Tags: c++11

There is a tuple implementation given [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44546/very-basic-tuple-implementation?newreg=2a069f7d250c4d978a8ce0569bbb1b62).

While the code compiles with gcc 4.8, with clang 3.5 it gives the following error: "expected expression" for the line `return tail.get<M-1>();`

I can't figure out what is wrong with the code and the error is not clear as to what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a dependent expression, so it should be

```
return tail.template get<M-1>();
```

Comment: There's technically not enough information to know that, but it does seem like the most likely reason.

Comment: Erm, I looked at the code. The code is ill-formed. It's 100% absolutely definitely the reason for the error.

Comment: Oh my, I completely overlooked the link he provided.  Hehehe, kindly disregard my comment.